# Looper для обновления виджетов

Tags: android, многопоточность, concurrency, android-handler

В приложении реализовано циклическое обновление виджетов с помощью хендлера. Код почти как тут, только в моем еще есть интерфейс:

```
// Create the Handler

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    // Define the code block to be executed
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          // Insert custom code here

          // Repeat every 2 seconds
          handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
        }
    };

    // Start the Runnable immediately
    handler.post(runnable);
```

Главный поток довольно сильно теряет в скорости отрисовки, да и сама реализация мне не нравиться. Есть мысли отправлять сообщения хендлеру, но на деле получиться приблизительно тоже самое. Какие еще есть альтернативные пути решения данной проблемы?

Comment: этот код будет исполняться только когда приложение запущено?

Comment: @Komdosh, да. Существует способ решить эту задачу используя корутины?

Comment: а что вы понимаете под корутинами в андроид на Java?

Comment: @Komdosh, кусок кода в вопросе намерено нашел на java для лучшего понимания.  Проект пишу на kotlin.

Comment: Тогда вопрос следует переформулировать, потому что на котлине несколько по другому нужно размышлять, корутины вряд ли тут помогут, потому что код будет похож на тот, что написали вы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `TimerTask`, если код должен выполняться, когда приложение запущено

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();

TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() { 
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                 //Ваш код
            }
        });
    }
};

timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 2000); //0 - начальная задержка, повторять каждые 2 секунды
```